# Timer MinValue, MaxValue, and Value in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

Ok I know this sounds odd, but to be honest, I do remember solving an example with timers in c# where I set the timer's minvalue, maxvalue, tick, interval etc... yet I don't remember/don't know how to do that it again, MVS 2019 won't show such parameters.

Any help would be really appreciated.

I am trying to start a row based on the value of the 7th index *AFTER* the datagridview (dg) is fully loaded from the database but, it is not working properly, either some rows are not loaded or it loaded but the O Complexity is VERY LOW (Program response is very BAD).

```
        private void Dg_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection con = GetConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Items", con);
        try
        {

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string PartName = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                string SN = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                string ModNum = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                string TS = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                string Man = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                string Brand = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                string Price = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                string Quan = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                string IPP = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                string HeadMat = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
                string Descibtion = reader.GetValue(10).ToString();
                string MinQuan = reader.GetValue(11).ToString();
                string MaxQuan = reader.GetValue(12).ToString();
                string PricePI = reader.GetValue(13).ToString();
                string ExpiryDate = reader.GetValue(14).ToString();
                string USDRate = reader.GetValue(15).ToString();

            }
            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        if (GetConnection().State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            Thread thread = new Thread(Blink);
            thread.Start();
            timer1.Stop();

        }
    }
```

Without this piece of code, the program runs just fine no problems what so ever

Here is the Blink method to handle the rows colour change and blinking.

```
   private void Blink(object o)
    {
        if (dg.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            while (dg.Rows.Count >= 0 && go)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
                {
                    int value = int.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                    if (value == 0 || value == 1)
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                    else if (value > 1 || value < 4)
                    {
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                    }
                    else
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
                go = true;
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                while (dg.Rows.Count != 0 && !go)
                {

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows)
                    {
                        int value1 = int.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
                        if (value1 == 0 || value1 == 1)
                        {
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                        }
                        else if (value1 > 1 || value1 < 4)
                        {
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                        }
                        else
                            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    }
                    go = false;
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what's the purpose of this code? You are getting data from database into reader and looping thru reader but not doing anything with the data. Why do you need that code?

Comment: I am filling a datagridview from a database and changing the background colour of each row if the value on the 7th index, the validation process must start ONLY when the datagridview is TOTALLY filled, I got it to work till now but I can not do anything with the data, I mean sell, duplicate, delete edit...

Comment: I think you need to read about how to load data in gridview first... Also Dg_CellPainting code you have shared doesn't do any thing apart from retrieve the data and looping thru reader.

Comment: Oh, let me edit my post. I forgot to the Blink Method... one second
Kindly check my post in few

Comment: Do NOT put that code in the `CellPainting` event. That event gets fired often. Considering “what” the code is doing… it is not surprising to see a performance drag. Also, what is the code supposed to do? The code in the `while (reader.Read()) …` loop is doing NOTHING. What is the purpose of that code? In addition, the code in the `Blink` method looks odd …`if (value > 1 || value < 4)` ? this looks strange. Are you sure you don’t want to use && instead of ||? The code is putting the `Thread` to sleep? What on earth are you trying to do with this code? You need to re-think this.

Comment: Ok, I re-thought it.
1. I need to retrieve the data from the database and fill it in the datagridvirew.
2. Once the datagridview is full (data retrieval is completed), the Blinking method should fire and last for 5 seconds, then stop leaving the colours of rows as red, yellow, or green depending on the value held by the 7th index of each row in the datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not want to dissuade you from doing this, however, if you will indulge me for a moment as I am having a difficult time trying to understand “why” you would want the rows to “blink” for a short amount of time. This seems odd to me as explained below.

> *I am somewhat leery of the “blinking” rows. I am not sure how this
> “blinking” of the rows for 5 seconds “HELPS” the user considering the
> row color is changed to a particular color in the end. I personally
> think the “blinking” is distracting/annoying and serves no purpose.
> Granted, possibly a “few” rows “blinking” when the data is loaded to
> indicate a problem with those rows. But even then, it is easy to
> imagine the user looking away at that moment and miss the “blinking”
> rows and what about the rows that are below the visible grid size?
> “Blinking” those rows makes no sense. So, I am not understanding “what
> purpose” this “blinking” rows serves? I would think that it would make
> more sense if the “blinking” never stopped until the user corrects the
> offending data.*

With that said, I suggest a closer look at what you currently have code wise. This code approach may well work, however in my tests, I am confident that the UI is going to act sluggish and will be slow to respond. Example, if you scroll the grid in either direction, you will notice how the display is sluggish and jumpy and not smooth as expected. Also, if you edit a cell and press the “Enter” key, you will notice a lag… it will take a second or two to drop down to the next cell.

This is mainly coming from the fact that the `Blink` code is executed FROM the grid’s `CellPainting` event. The grid’s `CellPainting` event gets fired OFTEN. It will fire when none of the cells have changed. Example, if the user “scrolls” the grid. Because of this, the `Blink` code will run unnecessarily since no cells have changed. In other words, the `Blink` method may run and change the rows back color when the rows are already the proper color. This is causing the sluggishness. The code is running the `Blink` method many more times than is needed.

You may be saying… *“well I run the `Blink` method under another thread.”* … with…

```
Thread thread = new Thread(Blink);
thread.Start();
```

And you would be correct… HOWEVER, this is actually “creating” even more problems in relation to sluggishness of the UI. If you step back and look at this, you should ask yourself… *“How many threads do I need?”* … This code is literally “creating” hundreds of `threads,` uses them ONCE and never disposes of them.

Example, let’s say the data has three (3) columns with twenty (20) rows. While loading the data into the grid, the grid’s `CellPainting` event will fire at least sixty (60) times (once for each cell). (I am confident it will actually fire more than this), however, even at 60 times, this will mean the code is creating at least 60 “separate” threads that never get disposed. Unabated, a crash should not be surprising.

You may somewhat alleviate this, if somewhere, the code properly disposes of the threads, however, in the codes current state, this is not possible since the `Thread` is “created”, started, and is never disposed in the same `if` statement. The variable `thread` will go out of scope (without properly being disposed) as soon as the `if` statement is exited.

Granted, once out of scope, the GC MAY dispose of this, however, I wouldn’t count on it to be quick about it. The main point here, is that starting multiple `Threads` for this just seems unnecessary and is problematic. In addition, my understanding is that when using `win forms`, it is better to use a `BackGroundWorker` instead of a `Thread.`

I am simply alluding to the fact that… if you DO use a thread/background worker for this, then only ONE background worker is really needed. We could use the same background worker over and over. Since it takes milliseconds for the code to execute, the worker will be done quickly. I could be mistaken, but I just do not see the need for a background worker here. In some cases, it may be needed and a whole different approach would be required.

***Blink code …***

In reference to the `Blink` code… it may well work, however, the user will never see this “changing” of the rows color. The user will not see the color changes as the code does not “Refresh” the grid. I assume this is why the sleep statement is there. The grid will not “automatically” refresh until the code exits the `Blink` method. The user will only see the final product. The user will not see the row colors change and the rows will appear to remain white.

You may consider simply calling the grids `Refresh` method, then sleep execution for a few milliseconds to allow the user to “see” the row color change. Unfortunately, this is not going to work. `Blink` is being called from the grids `CellPainting` event. If we call the grids `Refresh` method from `Blink`… that is going to “re-fire” the grids `CellPainting` event. A re-re-entrant error is almost guaranteed. This same idea would apply when the `Blink` method sets a rows color. This may re-fire the grid’s cell painting event again. All the more reason to avoid using this event.

Given all this and emphasizing my first comment, is should be clear that using the grids `CellPainting` event for this is probably not the best approach for numerous reasons. Most grid “painting” events fire often and for what the code is doing, we end up running the code more times than needed.

In this case, if the current code did execute, it is going to continue the “blinking” of the rows even after 5 seconds. Every time the grids `CellPainting` event fires, the code will call the `Blink` method and rows will start blinking. Eventually, the grid will start flashing like a Christmas tree and the UI will start to stall.

The main thing here, is that when using the “GRIDS” painting events, they are firing many more times than we need and we CAN get around this, however, considering that you only want the rows to “blink” for 5 seconds after the data loads, then after 5 seconds, why have the grid worry about it? This is something that should run for 5 seconds, then stop. So, bringing in the grids events seems like overkill. It can be done, but why. After the data loads, start a 5 second timer, start blinking the rows… then, after five seconds, stop the rows from blinking… done.

Given this, my approach does not use any of the grid’s events (yet). Instead of using the grids `CellPainting` event to call the `Blink` code… Let us go with your initial suggestion of using `Timers.` We could use two (2) timers. One timer will have an interval of 5000 and will keep track of the 5 seconds we want the rows to “blink” after the data is loaded into the grid. The second timer would have an interval of say 500 or 1/2 of a second. With each tick of this timer, we would call the `Blink` method to “toggle/blink” the row colors.

*A small trace of the current `Blink` code…*

If we start at the first `foreach` loop through the grid rows, if the cell at column 7 is a zero (0) or a one (1), then the code will color that row red. On the `else` portion we have… `if (value > 1 || value < 4)` … which I am confident you mean && to check for the numbers 2 and 3. Otherwise, you need to explain how this would ever be `false.` Assuming we want to use &&, this will color the row yellow when cell 7 values are 2 or 3.

Then if the cells value is not 0, 1, 2 or 3, then set that row color to green.

Continuing, the code needlessly freezes the UI and “sleeps” for 100 milliseconds. Then the code again starts a `foreach` loop through the rows in the grid. Here, I do not follow the logic, if ALL the rows are being set to white, then why check the value of cell 7? Checking for the value in cell 7 is unnecessary since the code is setting the rows to the same color (white).

It would appear, that a simpler approach would be to either “color” ALL the rows based on the cells value in column 7… OR … color ALL the rows white. This should simplify the code and we can use the timer to tell the code “which” way to color the rows… i.e., color the rows based on column 7 or color the rows white.

To help, we can create a global `bool` variable and call it `ColorOn.` We can use this variable to help us “toggle” the color state of the rows. If `ColorOn` is `true` and we run the `Blink` code it will color the rows based on the cell value at column 7. If `ColorOn` is `false`, then `Blink` will color the rows white.

Since we may be looping through the grids rows several times to color the rows, it may help if we create a method called `SetRowColor` that takes a `DataGridViewRow` and a `Boolean` value to indicate if we should make the row color “white” or color the row based on column 7. This method will come in handy when the code loops through the grid rows and changes the row color.

The `SetRowColor` method is below. First the code checks for the “new” row… we will ignore the grids “new” row if it exists. Next, a check is made on the `bool` `white` parameter. If it is `true`, then color the row white. If it is `false`, then color the row based on the value in column 7.

If we want to color the row based on the cell value in column (7) “TargetColumn.” A `TryParse` is used to safely validate the cells value as a number and place that number in the `out` variable `value.` Next a `switch` statement is used on the `value` variable to determine which color to set the row. 0 or 1, red; 2 or 3 yellow and any other number green.

```
private void SetRowColor(DataGridViewRow row, bool white) {
  if (row.IsNewRow) {
    return;
  }
  if (white) {
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
  }
  else {
    if (int.TryParse(row.Cells["TargetColumn"].Value.ToString(), out int value)) {
      switch (value) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
          row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
          break;
        case 2:
        case 3:
          row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
          break;
        default:
          row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We can use the `SetRowColor` method in the new `Blink` method and it may look like below. Following the code, a check is made on the `ColorOn` variable...

- If `true,` then loop through all the rows and set each row color based on the cells value in column 7.
- If `false,` then loop through all the rows and set each row color to white.

We will call this `Blink` method in the `MilliSecondTimer_Tick` event.

```
private void Blink() {
  if (ColorOn) {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows) {
      SetRowColor(row, false);
    }
  }
  else {
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dg.Rows) {
      SetRowColor(row, true);
    }
  }
}
```

This looks cleaner and it will take milliseconds to execute.

Now that we have the `Blink` method set up, next we need a `Timer` to call it. This timer’s interval needs to be set such that it defines how “often” we want the rows color to toggle. Example, if we set the interval to 1 second, then the rows will change color every second. With each tick, we call `Blink`, then toggle the `ColorOn` variable to change the color next time around. This `MilliSecondTimer_Tick` event may look like…

```
private void MilliSecondTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Blink();
  ColorOn = !ColorOn;
}
```

If we run this, the timers tick event will fire at every interval and toggle the row colors but it does not stop after five seconds. It is possible to “check” the amount of time that has elapsed since the timer was first started, and if it is greater than 5 seconds, then stop the timer. This is doable; however, I am going the lazy route and use a second timer with an interval of 5 seconds.

Start this five second timer at the same time as the “blink” timer. Then, after 5 seconds has elapsed, its tick event will fire where we can turn off the “blink” timer and also stop its own timer as it is no longer needed. Since we want the rows to “remain” in a colored state after the “blinking” we need to set the `ColorOn` to `true` and call the `Blink` method one last time. Simply stopping the timers may leave the grid in a state such that ALL the rows are colored white. This `FiveSecondTimer_Tick` event may look something like…

```
private void FiveSecondTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MilliSecondTimer.Stop();
  FiveSecondTimer.Stop();
  ColorOn = true;
  Blink();
}
```

A helper method is used to set up and start the global `Timer`s. We set the interval, subscribe (wire up) to the timer’s tick event and start the timers. We will call this method right after the data is loaded. To note, if you decrease the `MilliSecondTimer` `interval` the rows will “blink” faster and obviously, a larger number will “blink” slower. The five second timer’s interval is set to 5 seconds. Increasing its interval will allow the rows to continue “blinking” longer than 5 seconds.

```
private void StartTimers() {
  FiveSecondTimer.Interval = 5000;
  MilliSecondTimer.Interval = 500;
  FiveSecondTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(FiveSecondTimer_Tick);
  MilliSecondTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MillSecondTimer_Tick);
  MilliSecondTimer.Start();
  FiveSecondTimer.Start();
}
```

A method to get some test data `GetDT` is created. A `DataTable` is used as a data source to the grid. It has three (3) columns, such that the “target” column we want to check the values with is in column 2. Its name is ”TargetColumn” and this name is used in the `SetRowColor` method instead of the column index number. Then the table is filled with thirty (30) rows, such that the `TargetColumn` values will come from a random number generator with random numbers from 0 to 6.

```
private DataTable GetDT() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Col0", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("TargetColumn", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
  Random rand = new Random();
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add("COR" + i, rand.Next(0, 7), "C2R" + i);
  }
  return dt;
}
```

***Putting all this together…***

[image]

To put all this together and test, the code below should demonstrate what is described above. Create a new win forms project, drop a `DataGridView` onto the form as shown above and re-name the grid to `dg` using the OPs grid name… `dg.` Running the code should “blink” the rows in the grid for 5 seconds and after the 5 seconds will leave the rows in a colored state.

```
DataTable GridDT;
bool ColorOn = true;
System.Windows.Forms.Timer FiveSecondTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
System.Windows.Forms.Timer MilliSecondTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  GridDT = GetDT();
  dg.DataSource = GridDT;
  StartTimers();
}
```

***What happens if the user “changes” the value in one of the target column’s cells?***

Now that we have the coloring and the blinking of the rows done, you may ask yourself, *”What happens if the user (or code) changes one of the cells values that is in the “target” column?”* The color will not change and we may have to run the `Blink` code again.

This is where one of the grids events will come in handy. The grids, `CellValueChanged` event will fire when the user changes a cells value and tries to “leave” the cell. If we wire up (subscribe) to this event, we could run the `Blink` code again. But this seems like overkill. In other words, only ONE (1) cell has changed, it seems unnecessary to loop through ALL the rows. And we already know which row it is.

In this case, we only want to change the row color when a “TargetColumn” cell changes value. If the other column value’s change, we can ignore those. We are only concerned with the “TargetColumn” cells changing. Below is the identical code as the `Blink` code however it does not loop through all the grid rows… it only re-colors the row that changed. Using the `SetRowColor` method makes things a little easier.

```
private void dg_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dg.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "TargetColumn") {
    if (dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["TargetColumn"].Value != null) {
      SetRowColor(dg.Rows[e.RowIndex], false);
    }
  }
}
```

This should complete the example. Please forgive my long-winded rant. I hope it makes sense and helps.

Comment: You solved this problem down to the root and added solutions for some other thoughts I had in mind. The editing part, I have a button which opens another form and passes all data of the CurrentSelectedRow from parent to child (form1 to form2) expect the primary key then updates the newly edited values to the DB where the primary keys match without updating the primary key or changing it. Thank you dearly it worked AMAZINGLY.